# How to get control choices from $setting object passed to sanitize_callback

Tags: theme-customizer, callbacks

## Example Code

Working with the Customizer API.

Setting added (example) like so:

```
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'theme_oenology_options[' . $option_parameter['name'] . ']', array(
        'default'           => $option_parameter['default'],
        'type'              => 'option',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'oenology_sanitize_' . $option_parameter['sanitize']
    ) );
```

Control added (example) like so:

```
        $wp_customize->add_control( 
            'oenology_' . $option_parameter['name'], 
            $customizer_control_parameters 
        );
```

Note: `$customizer_control_parameters` is an array defined elsewhere. For select-type controls (select, radio, radio-image, etc.) it includes a `'choices'` key.

Sanitize callback defined (example) like so:

```
function oenology_sanitize_select( $input ) {
    return sanitize_key( $input );
}
```

Everything works flawlessly in the Customizer. The control is displayed, the setting is configurable, and the sanitization works.

## Problem

All good so far, but it would be better to whitelist the setting against pre-defined choices in `$wp_customize->add_control()`. Let's use the second parameter passed to `'sanitize_callback'`, `$setting`, to get the `'choices'` defined in the control!

[Core reference](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-setting.php#L292):

```
return apply_filters( "customize_sanitize_{$this->id}", $value, $this );
```

## Solution Attempts

```
function oenology_sanitize_select( $input, $setting ) {
    $input = sanitize_key( $input );
    $choices = array(); // See below
    return ( array_key_exists( $input, $choices ) ? $input : $setting->default );
}
```

Problem: using either of the two methods below does not return the array of choices passed to `$wp_customize->add_control()`:

1. Using `$wp_customize`  global object:

   ```
   global $wp_customize;
   $control = $wp_customize->get_control( $setting->id );
   $choices = $control->choices;
   ```
2. Using `$setting->manager` object:

   ```
   $choices = $setting->manager->get_control( $setting->id )->choices;
   ```

In both cases, `get_control( $setting->id )` returns a `null`, instead of an object.

## Question

How do I get `'choices'` from `$wp_customize->get_control()`, using the `$this` object passed to `"customize_sanitize_{$this->id}"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct:

```
$control = $setting->manager->get_control($setting->id);
$choices = $control->choices;
```

However, in your example, `$setting->id` will be `theme_oenology_options[name]`.

So, `get_control('theme_oenology_options[name]')` will return null because there's no control with that name. You gave the control the id of `oenology_name` instead.

I always give the same ID to settings and their matching controls for that reason.