# Can not sanitize select control in customize api

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

I am using wordpress 4.7.2 .

I am creating a customization section for my custom theme. This is my select control.

```
 $wp_customize->add_setting( $this->slug . '_blog[pagination_type]', array(
            'default'           => 'classic-pagination',
            'transport'         => 'postMessage',
            'type'              => 'theme_mod',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'my_theme_sanitize_select',
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_control( $this->slug . '_blog[pagination_type]', array(
            'label'    => 'Pagination Type',
            'section'  => $this->slug . '_blog_section',
            'type'     => 'select',
            'choices'  => array(
                'classic-pagination' => 'Classic Pagination',
                'load-more-button'   => 'Load More Button'
                ),
            'priority' => 18,
        ) );
```

and my sanitize_callback function is

```
public function my_theme_sanitize_select( $input, $setting ) {
    // Ensure input is a slug
    $input = sanitize_key( $input );
    // Get list of choices from the control
    // associated with the setting
    $choices = $setting->manager->get_control( $setting->id )->choices;
    // If the input is a valid key, return it;
    // otherwise, return the default
    return ( array_key_exists( $input, $choices ) ? $input : $setting->default );
}
```

Displaying error Invalid value , when trying to save data.

I tried even with just sanitize_key function but can not get it correct

```
public function my_theme_sanitize_select( $input ) {
        return sanitize_key( $input );
    }
```

and then even to

```
public function my_theme_sanitize_select( $input ) {
        return $input;
    }
```

and

```
public function my_theme_sanitize_select( $input ) {
        return true;
    }
```

but when I am not calling to any sanitization function it is working correctly . that means I am making some mistake in creating the sanitize_callback() but in [reference](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/2015/06/11/moving-to-the-customizer-api-from-the-settings-api-using-options-api/) too the callback function has same naming and same function definition.

after that I searched for similar problem and got [one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190694/how-to-get-control-choices-from-setting-object-passed-to-sanitize-callback)  but could not solve this issue, please help me.

I gone through the core codes and found in `WP_Customize_Setting` class `sanitize()` my input data is becoming `null` . but could not get more idea.

Comment: where are you putting all this? is a class? or in functions.php?

Comment: @DavidLee A class . registering through constructor of parent class.

Answer (score 1):

The `add_setting` logic cant find the `my_theme_sanitize_select` function, you need to tell it where it is:

```
'sanitize_callback'    => array( $this, 'my_theme_sanitize_select' ),
```

remember that your function is inside a class so it cant just be accessed, add this to your class:

```
public function my_theme_sanitize_select( $input, $setting ) {
    $from_parent = my_theme_sanitize_select( $input, $setting );
    return $from_parent;
}
```

Comment: sanitization function is in parent class of this class, so it should is able to access it, the issue might be something else.

Comment: let me update the answer, please give it a try.

Comment: thank you for your effort buddy, but sadly No success with it. :( Can you please suggest any other possible option ?

Comment: i updated my answer, you are getting an invalid value data null because the function scope

Comment: This also giving same error. I create this method in the same class I am creating control , but got same error . :(

Comment: try removing `public`

Comment: Sorry for late reply dear, I left office after that yesterday, just tried and still no success :(